# Getting row of UITableView cell on button press swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, swift3

I have this code working on swift 2, it's serve to getting row of UITableView cell on button press:

```
@IBAction func commentsButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    let btnPos: CGPoint = sender.convert(point:CGPoint.zero, toView: self.tableView)
    let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: btnPos)! as NSIndexPath
    passaValor = indexPath.row
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "searchToComments", sender: self)
}
```

In swift 3 I receive this error

> Cannot invoke 'convert' with an argument list of type '(point:
>   CGPoint, toView: UITableView!)'

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of the method has been changed under Swift 3. It is now:

```
    func convert(CGPoint, to: UIView?)
```

Therefore you would call it as:

```
    sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.tableView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
myButton.addTarget(self, action: "connected:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside))
```

And you need to this

```
myButton.tag = indexPath.row

func connected(sender: UIButton){
    let buttonTag = sender.tag
}
```

Hope this helps.